# Apple watch app distribution without watch

Tags: ios, apple-watch, appstore-approval

Is it possible to submit an app with apple watch support to App Store without apple watch. Its too expensive for me, but i want to make support for others, who have.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. Apple can't and won't check if you own the device.

Be aware that your app may work in a different way on a real device or even crash. You should always test your App on all devices it supports.